# How to browse to the IIS homepage on an external device after installing Windows Server 2012?

Tags: ip, windows-server-2012, iis

I installed Windows Server 2012, in my home network I can type the ip address of the server in any browser, on any device and the IIS homepage opens up.

When I want to open the website on an external device, for instance my iPhone (3G), I don't get that IIS homepage.

How can I succeed in opening websites from my Windows Server 2012 with external devices (devices that aren't in my home network) ?

Comment: Forward all data on the port you have assigned to the specific intra-net address you have configured the server to have.

Comment: You ,may need to be a bit more specific @Ramhound. Port forwarding isn't the easiest concept.

Comment: @JoshCampbell - The user inteface expose on 100% of the consumer market routers makes it trivial to read the manual for his device and look up port forwarding.  Port Forwarding is a very simply concept, if its not, looking up information is required.

Comment: Your 3G is looking at publicly exposed websites. Your network is local

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through quite a few steps before you can access a website from outside your home network. Since you have IIS installed I'm assuming you also have the DNS service installed.

**What you need to do (short answer):**

1. You need to go into your router `Admin Panel` and point the `HTTP` service on `port 80` (default) to the local IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.5) of the Server 2012 machine.
2. If you type in your public IP address from a device on an external network, it will open the Default website hosted on your version of `IIS`. As far as I'm aware you can't access multiple websites using a single IP address.
3. The best way to access multiple websites would be to obtain a domain name, add a `New Zone` file for that domain name in your `DNS Manager` and add an `A-Record (Host)` within that zone file for each website you want to host.

For example: If I purchase a domain name called `mywebsite.co.uk`, I would first have to add a `New Zone` called `mydomain.co.uk` in my `DNS Manager`. Once I've done that I would add a `www` A-Record for my main website, a `blog` A-Record for my blog and any other A-Records for any other websites I may want. The number of `Host Names` you can add is entirely dependent on who you purchased/obtained the domain name from.

1. After setting up the above on your side, you would also have to make changes to the `Zone File` provided by your domain name provider (e.g. `GoDaddy`). The main changes include pointing the `@(Host)` to your public IP address and adding `CNames (Aliases)` for each website you're/you will be hosting.
2. Finally you would need to Edit the bindings of an existing/new website (using `IIS`) so that the website knows what its `Host Name` is.

For example, for my hypothetical website `(www.mydomain.co.uk)`, in the website bindings I would have to specify the `Host Name` as `www.mydomain.co.uk`, the port as `80` and `IP address` as unassigned (this is because a single IP address will be pointing to numerous websites).

I can go into more detail, but you really need to do some more research and experiment some more.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you need to you pc to connect with internet and then get your current internet ip address:
Suppose you have `ip: 110.212.89.10:8080` and you IIS page start from `/myIISPage` then just type it in your device browser as : `110.212.89.10:8080/myIISPage`

but remember this will work only if you server is directly connected to internet means from LAN wire. Internet access from Wifi internet won't be helpful.